# Excel VBA: How to use a variable for VisibleItemsList?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to control a Pivot table's filter by using VBA and I'm struggling to correctly using the *"VisibleItemsList"* with a variable that contains the filters settings, I'll post the code for a better understandig:

```
Public Sub updatePivotTable(param2Set() As Variant)
    'Array("[Budget].[AM].&[Aeffe USA]","[Budget].[AM].&[Alberganti]","[Budget].[AM].&[Blokh]","[Budget].[AM].&[Bondi]")
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim parametersCount As Integer
        parametersCount = UBound(param2Set)
    Dim filters As String
    'filters = "Array("
    For y = 0 To parametersCount - 1
        filters = filters + """[Budget].[AM].&[" & param2Set(y) & "]"", "
    Next y
        filters = filters + """[Budget].[AM].&[" & param2Set(y) & "]"""
    With Sheets("Export BUDG")
            .PivotTables("pvtToExport").PivotFields("[Budget].[AM].[AM]").VisibleItemsList = Array(filters)
    End With
End Sub
```

The error I get is:

> Query (1, 28) Sintax ',' incorrect. ("[Budget].[AM].&[Caprioli]",
>   "[Budget].[AM].&[Bondi]")."

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Filters needs to be an array of separate values, not a single string shoved into an array.

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be: .PivotTables("pvtToExport").PivotFields("[Budget].[AM].[AM]").VisibleItemsList = Split(filters, ",")

Comment: @jkpieterse I've try your way and also 'PivotTables("pvtToExport").PivotFields("[Budget].[AM].[AM]").VisibleItemsList = Array(Split(filters, ","))' but still no good